# How to check who created VM and other resources in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I believe this used to be the `actor` key, but I no longer see this in the logs in Stackdriver.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview

How can I find which account provisioned a given resource?

Comment: I still see "actor". Perhaps you can expand your question with how you are creating a GCE VM instance, what you are seeing in Stackdriver and what you expected to see. You can also use `protoPayload.authenticationInfo`.

Comment: This is available via the Stackdriver logging page or via the activity logs (Home -> Activity tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to all activity in the activity tab, in the home page of your project. But it's very manual

One of the best practice is to use Stackdriver logs. And especially to create a sink of the logs that you want to oversee into BigQuery. Indeed the audit log info are kept only 13 months (400 days exactly) and you could want to perform search above this limit.
And it's very interesting because you can perform these sink at folder or organisation level.
Finally, having data into BigQuery allow you to script your search/warning by simply query your table.

More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-working-with-google-cloud-audit-logging)

Comment: so you'd use Stackdrivers, BigQuery instead of something like ELK stack?

Comment: I prefer built in product. It's easier and cheap. But you can you the stack that you prefer for the analytics.